# How to activate functionality only in developer mode

Tags: android

I have application with in app billing. I'm using the [AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary) to manage the purchase.

I would like to be able to have access to all the buyable option when i run the app in debug mode.

Currently when i need to test an option i replace something like this :

```
bool option = BillingController.isPurchased(this,OPTION_NAME);
```

by

```
bool option = true;//BillingController.isPurchased(this,OPTION_NAME);
```

Clearly not a good solution !

Is it safe todo something like this ? :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public static final bool DEBUG = true;
}

if(MyApp.DEBUG)
    option = true;
else
    option = BillingController.isPurchased(this,OPTION_NAME);
```

Is there any better solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get debug value using application info service.

```
boolean DEBUG = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
```

Comment: How to get the debug state was not really the question but rather how to properly use this information

Comment: Out of curiosity, where would you put this so that it is accessible across the entire application?